# How to group two CABasicAnimation animations and kick them off at the exact same time?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I know there is some kind of animation grouping mechanism in core animation. So lets say I have two CABasicAnimation `firstAnimation` and `secondAnimation`. How would I group these and how would I kick off the group to start animating?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use the CAAnimationGroup class. Create an array containing the animations you want, and set the AnimationGroup's `animations` property to that array. CAAnimationGroup is a subclass of CAAnimation, so you can add it to a layer using `[layer addAnimation:forKey:]` like you would a regular animation. Once added to a layer, all animations in a group execute concurrently.

I would suggest reading the [CAAnimationGroup Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimationGroup_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAAnimationGroup/animations) first. There are a number of implementation details worth understanding before you use it. For example:

1. The `delegate` property of individual animations is ignored.
2. The `removeOnCompletion` property of individual animations is ignored.
3. The AnimationGroup has its own `delegate` and `removeOnCompletion` properties.
4. Animations aren't time-scaled to the group, so if an individual animation has a duration longer than that of the group object, it will be interrupted at the end of the group's duration.
5. The `animations` property of CAAnimationGroup is copied, not retained.