# Is there is a way that do CATransition and display a label in front of animation?

Tags: iphone

I try to display a UILabel in front of CATransition animation using insertSubView

```
 [self.view insertSubview:myLabel atIndex:10000];
```

but it does not work.
Is there is a way that do CATransition and display a label in front of animation?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CAAnimationGroup class to make 2 concurrent animations, your animation and the appearance of your UILabel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any sample codes? this is really new to me

Comment: Just follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892883/how-to-group-two-cabasicanimation-animations-and-kick-them-off-at-the-exact-same/2893363#2893363